# Need working xpath to capture xml all attributes and text separately, check the below

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt, attributes

how to get the all attribute values CacheVM,junk,bcd and text values JVM1,JVM2,JVM3 separately in xslt ,

```
<request>
    <args src="url">
        <arg name="CacheVM">JVM1</arg>
        <arg name="junk">JVM2</arg>
        <arg name="bcd">JVM3</arg>
    </args>
</request>
```

I tried getting using the below xpaths, variable - vQueryAttribute (xml stored in this variable)

```
<xsl:variable name="vQueryAttribute" 
  select="string($vQueryParam/request/args/arg/@[localname()='name'])"
/>
<xsl:variable name="QueryText" 
  select="string($vQueryParam/request/args/arg[@name])"/>
```

Comment: Please post your code **as code** within your question, not as links to images. Also include the expected result (also as code).

Comment: I tired doing in the code section but it's so confusing giving lot of errors for posting it, that's the reason i posted as picture
i am expecting all attributes values and text values seperately but the xpath i am using it's giving me only the first tag attribute,text value not picking up the second tag values

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help

Comment: can i know are you able to see the image?

Comment: I am afraid you are missing the point. Images are useless when one wants to reproduce the problem. No one is going to waste their time by retyping the code.

Comment: I removed the image and added it as text

Comment: What does "to get all ... separately" mean exactly? Do you want a sequence of string values? Anyway, tell us first whether you use XSLT 1 or XSLT 2 or 3.

Comment: I am using xslt  1 and i need to pick all name attribute values (Cachevm,junk,bcd) & text (JVM1,JVM2,JVM3)separately

Comment: What do you mean by "I need to pick all name..."? You want to output the values in a text file? You want to generate a different XML structure? ...?

Comment: Need to get all values and store it in context variable,

Answer (score 0):

If it is XSLT 1 then, in a single variable value, you can bind the attribute nodes with e.g. `/request/args/arg/@name`. There is no way to bind a single variable to the three attribute string values (you could do that in XSLT 2/XPath 2 or later with e.g. `data(/request/args/arg/@name)` or `/request/args/arg/@name/string()`.

To bind the three elements, you can use `/request/args/arg[@name]` as well, again, in XSLT 1 with XPath 1 there is no way to bind the string values in a single variable, you can just bind nodes/a node-set.

Comment: Thanks somuch bro

I think then there is only option of forloop

Comment: While you can of course build a variable with an `xsl:for-each` inside, it will in XSLT 1.0 be a result tree fragment with nodes of which you can then get a single string value, but not a sequence or set of strings.